# How to uncycle a cycled iterator?

Tags: python, list, iterator, cycle

Here is my list, which I have converted into `iter`, then into `cycle`:

```py
from itertools import cycle

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
itr = iter(lst)
ccl = cycle(lst)
```

How can I convert it back into a `list` — is there any `from itertools import uncycle`?

My final goal is to shuffle it with `random.shuffle`

Comment: Why not just use `lst`?

Comment: You cannot unshuffle afaik, you have the original list to shuffle and create another iter cycle

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments you cannot directly shuffle a generator. What you can do is take a slice of it with `iterator.islice` up to the length of the list and then shuffle:

```
from itertools import islice

uncycled = list(islice(ccl, 0, len(lst)))
random.shuffle(uncycled)

print(uncycled)
# [2, 1, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the final goal is *cycling a shuffled list*, no need to play with chain of "cycle/slice, cycling/uncycling".
You can rich the goal with custom generator function:

```
from random import shuffle

def cycle_shuffled(lst):
    lst = lst[:]
    while True:
        shuffle(lst)
        yield lst

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
gen = cycle_shuffled(lst)

print(next(gen))   # [3, 2, 4, 1]
print(next(gen))   # [1, 3, 4, 2]
print(next(gen))   # [2, 4, 3, 1]
```